# Form validation with Javascript not working

Tags: javascript

I purchased [this script](http://classicforms.workforfood.pro/full/prf/forms/startup-ms.html) to build my forms. His demo is working fine but on my version [on this link](http://www.ftouhmills.com/order/forms/startup-ms.html) the next button do not validate the form fields, instead it produce a js error when checked on Google console.

Google console produce this js error : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).writeDebug is not a function.

Thanks for any help, because the script vendor do not reply to any email.

Comment: First of all you have a syntax error SyntaxError: missing ; before statement in this file plugin.forms.min.js

Comment: Jquery needs to be referenced before the use of Jquery tags such as `$(...)`

Comment: $.fn.writeDebug=function(){}

Comment: @RobertNegreanu sorry for my js skills, but in the file plugin.forms.min.js where should I put the missing semi colon  ? after what section of code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The writeDebug function is defined inside plugins.forms.min.js, but there is a syntax error.

So maybe your function is not defined because the script itself is messed up. Try fixing that semi-colon problem and it might be ok.

Comment: Sorry for my js skills, but where can I find that semicolon ? is it a missing semi colon ? in what js file should I look ? Thanks

Comment: When you load your page, you can then inspect it. Go into the console tab, and will have these : 
14:05:28,078 SyntaxError: missing ; before statement[En savoir plus]  plugin.forms.min.js:1:506
14:05:28,216 TypeError: $(...).writeDebug is not a function[En savoir plus]  wrenchbar.js:4:14  So it looks like there is an error in plugins.forms.min.js. Is it a script you minified yourself or is it just a third-party library ?

Comment: document.selection.clear()}}method.killCtrlA=function(event)     There should be a semi-colon before the method.killCtrlA imo

Comment: Thanks Bernard, it worked. There was many missing semi colons and stuff in the minified file, I search Google for unminify js file, then uploaded an unminified version. Thanks again.